# Solving $\sin80^\circ\sin20^\circ\sin x = \sin 10^\circ\sin60^\circ\sin(30^\circ+x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

> Solve:
> $$\sin80^\circ\sin20^\circ\sin x = \sin 10^\circ\sin60^\circ\sin(30^\circ+x)$$

I tried cancelling $\sin10^\circ$

$$\sin80^\circ\cdot 2\cos10^\circ\cdot\sin x=\sin60^\circ\sin(30+x)$$

$$\frac{2\sin^280^\circ}{\sin60^\circ} = \frac{\sin(30^\circ+x)}{\sin x}$$

Then I'm stuck.

Comment: @player3236 You are only saying that $x=0$ happens not to be one of the solutions. Note, the formula is not claimed to be an _identity_ holding for all $x$; it is meant to be an _equation_ to which we want to describe further that set of $x$ that satisfies the equation. A priory, that set could be empty, contain one single element (unique solution), or contain many solutions.

Answer (score 4):

We have $$\frac{\sin80^{\circ}\sin20^{\circ}}{\sin10^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{2}\cot{x}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{4\sin80^{\circ}\cos10^{\circ}}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}-\sqrt3=\cot{x}$$ or
$$\cot{x}=\frac{8\cos^210^{\circ}-3}{\sqrt3}$$ or
$$\cot{x}=\frac{1+4\cos20^{\circ}}{\sqrt3}.$$
Now,  $$\frac{1+4\cos20^{\circ}}{\sqrt3}=\frac{\sin20^{\circ}+2\sin40^{\circ}}{\sqrt3\sin20^{\circ}}=\frac{\cos10^{\circ}+\sin40^{\circ}}{\sqrt3\sin20^{\circ}}=$$
$$==\frac{\sin80^{\circ}+\sin40^{\circ}}{\sqrt3\sin20^{\circ}}=\frac{\sqrt3\cos20^{\circ}}{\sqrt3\sin20^{\circ}}=\cot20^{\circ}.$$
Can you end it now?